# Xcode 5.0 crash on Mavericks

Tags: crash, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I recently updated both OSX and Xcode. Now I can't open any storyboard, because Xcode crashes every time I try to. I downloaded Xcode 5.0.1, tried to run the project on different OSX user's account - nothing changed.

Error log: http://hastebin.com/dapitesalu.avrasm

What can cause the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify the context a bit more? Does Xcode crash when you open a new project? How about re-opening in Xcode 4.6.3 (does that still work)? In Xcode please confirm that you are using the latest command line tools with the correct version of the project.